# Uses 'await' on an instance of 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> Function([GetOptions?])', which is not a subtype of 'Future'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this exception in my code.

 Uses 'await' on an instance of 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> Function([GetOptions?])', which is not a subtype of 'Future'

```
var  firebaseuid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
DocumentSnapshot userdoc = (await usercollection.doc(firebaseuid).get) as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
var alldocs = videoscollection.get();
```

I tried to remove await but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parantheses on your `usercollection.doc(firebaseuid).get()`

 Follow the below mentioned code

```
var firebaseuid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
DocumentSnapshot userdoc = (await usercollection.doc(firebaseuid).get()) as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
var alldocs = videoscollection.get();
```